# Possible to pause PHP script, get GPS location using HTML/JS, then resume PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, gps, geolocation

I'm making a PHP script that needs the location of the user before it outputs data to the user.

The only reliable way of getting the location is using Javascript, "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition"

This causes trouble, since it does take some time before the location is retrieved.

The simple solution is to first present a page to retrieve the location, and when retrived, show a button that the user clicks to reload the page (or reload automatically).

But the neatest solution would be to have this done on the same page load (PHP scripts waits for JS to finish, then resumes).

Is there any way to do this?

PHP first outputs geolocation JS, PHP script pauses, when location retrieved JS then messages PHP script some way, PHP script continues.

Comment: if you need the data then collect it before and pass the values to the php script before it is running. you can't pause the lifecircle of a php script execution to get data from js

Comment: I was thinking there might be a "thread ID" or execution ID or something like that could be passed on to JS, and then JS sent a ajax request that told the server to resume that execution. But i guess this is not possible.

Comment: sry this is not possible, you need to collect this information first.

Answer (score 2):

There is no usefull way to pause a php script.

The neatest way for your job is to print the HTML code containing a placeholder (div) for the map oder ohter data, wait for the coord, send them as a ajax request to your PHP script, and then replace the empty div container (placeholder) with the real data.

Comment: I agree. Ajax runs asynchronously, so it can run while the rest of the page is running. Hide the area with css, and then display the area with the data when the Ajax has returned the data from your PHP script

Comment: But I use PHP to output everything (include header.php etc), so I guess there's no way to do this without refreshing the page (running the script again)?

Answer (score 0):

There is not way to pause php script, even if you could thats bad practice. For this kind stuff javascript callbacks and ajax is best solution. The first parameter of

```
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options)
```

is success callback, so if you put your ajax request to server that runs your php script. It will load your location, and only if it successfully found your location, it will fire success callback which will be your ajax request, and after success of your ajax you can generate your html with javascript

something like this

```
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/request/path',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){

        }
    });
 }, error, options)
```

if your are not good with ajax this is jQuery ajax manual for you
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

I hope it helps